# How do you pass variables from c# to javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, variables

Looking to pass variables from c# to javascript to use some jquery code. Passing doubles, ints, strings, arrays. Does anyone know how to do this?

for example if I have this code snip in c#:

```
string blah = "this is a blah string";
```

I would like to pass this into javascript so that I could use a mouseover event in jquery:

```
$('#myDiv').mouseover(function(){ //do something with my 'blah' string });
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nevermind I think I figured it out. Assuming the code above, you can write in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var JavascriptBlah = '<%=blah%>'</script>
```

This will pass the blah in c# to the JavascriptBlah on the client side. Then you can manipulate on client side.

Comment: The downside to this is that if "blah" has a single-quote in it, you're in trouble.  There's sense in converting your string to JSON first before passing it.

Comment: Does anyone know if using "<%=VariableName%>, is functional if the variable "blah" is being assigned a value with a "private async Task Foo()"
I have it being assigned in a private async task and I'm wondering if that's the reason why it's not working for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use public properties on the code behind as well as the session. Here is a sample using public properties that can be read from a Javascript function.

**Front End:**

```
function IsAgentInProgram()
{
    var optStatus = "<%=AgentOptInStatus%>";

    if (optStatus == "True")
        alert("You are opted in!");
    else
        alert ("You are opted OUT");
}
```

Code Behind:

```
public bool AgentOptInStatus;

private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.AgentOptInStatus = true;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently used this [ToJson()](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/01/tip-trick-building-a-tojson-extension-method-using-net-3-5.aspx) extension method along with [Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock.aspx) Method to pass down a multi-level mapping object that populates three levels of cascaded dropdowns.

Comment: not sure what you mean here, but could you see above for the edited portion?

Comment: **WARNING**

Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock is obsolite since [Framework v.4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ee471421(v=VS.100).aspx). [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx) method is now recommended.

Answer (score 1):

you can use asp:HiddenField variables to pass values between codebehind and js..
this accomplished with viewstate of page during postbacks...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252222/access-an-asphiddenfield-control-in-javascript the link has a sample code by this way you may access value of hiddenfield either code behind  or javascript