# How to forward MultiMap .Net to Java?

Tags: c#, java, .net, web-services, multimap

I am currently working on an application which needs to send MultiMap from .Net to Java. I am currently using "org.apache.commons.collections.MultiMap" in Java to read details from MultiMap and thinking to use MultiMap class in C# to forward the details from .Net to Java.

I would like to forward MultiMap from .Net to Java using webservice.

Can I use this approach to forward the details from .Net to Java (because I need to use one key and multiple values) ?

If so, can anyone explain the procedure to forward the details ?

Comment: What do you mean with "forward"? How do you "send" data from .Net to Java?

Comment: I would like to forward MultiMap using webservice

Comment: Why not just send it as Json through the webservice?

Comment: I really don't have much idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are two independent applications, there is no way for them to see each others' variables without an explicit communication channel.  Your best bet is to open some sort of Socket between the two and specify how you want to data over the line to be structured.

JSON example(you probably don't need to do this manually, check for a [library](http://www.json.org/) do to the object->JSON conversion.

```
{
    {
        "key":"mykey"
        "values":["val1","val2","val3"]    
    }

    {
        "key":"mykey2"
        "values":["val12","val22","val32"]    
    }
}
```

Once you know your data format and have a socket connection, you just need the C# and Java to be able to convert to and from the data format.

If you meant javascript interacting with server side C#, there are ways to bind variables but I don't know if they work with complex data types.  [How do you pass variables from c# to javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553680/how-do-you-pass-variables-from-c-sharp-to-javascript)