# Need to pass a C# string to a javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you pass variables from c# to javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553680/how-do-you-pass-variables-from-c-sharp-to-javascript)

I have a C# method that validates the user credentials during Login.

```
public string CreateLoginjson(string strErrorType, bool blIsAuthenticated)
{
    StringBuilder sbLoginJson = new StringBuilder();
    if (blIsAuthenticated)
    {
        sbLoginJson.Append("{LoginSuccess:1");
    }
    else
    {
        sbLoginJson.Append("{LoginSuccess:0");
    }

    if (strErrorType != string.Empty)
    {
        if (strErrorType.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) == "Token")
        {
            sbLoginJson.Append(",txtTestTokenNumber1:\"Error\"");
            sbLoginJson.Append(",txtTestTokenNumber2:\"Error\"");
            sbLoginJson.Append(",txtTestTokenNumber3:\"Error\"");
            sbLoginJson.Append(",txtTestTokenNumber4:\"Error\"");

        }
        else if (strErrorType.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) == "Password")
        {
            sbLoginJson.Append(",txtPassword:\"Error\"");

        }
        else if (strErrorType.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) == "UserName")
        {
            sbLoginJson.Append(",UserName:\"Error\"");

        }

    }
    sbLoginJson.Append("}");

    return sbLoginJson.ToString();


}
```

I now have to pass the string sbLoginJson to a Javascript function, which checks if the user has failed to provide the login details.

Java Script Function, that I have written so far.

```
function GetLoginJson(strLoginJson) {
    if (strLoginJson != "" && strLoginJson != undefined) {
        var objLoginJson = eval('"+strLoginJson+"');
    }
    if(objLoginJson.sbLoginJson())
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me how to pass the string & make it work?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Create a protected property and set it somewhere in your code:

```
protected string LoginJson { get; set; }
```

Then use it like so:

```
var strLoginJson = '<% =LoginJson %>';
```

You can also call your public method directly as well, however, considering that your method is related to authentication, I would not recommend this:

```
var strLoginJson = '<% = CreateLoginjson(a, b) %>';
```

Comment: I rewrote my JS as  :                                                        function GetLoginJson(strLoginJson) {
    if (strLoginJson != '' && strLoginJson != undefined) {
        var objLoginJson = eval('"+strLoginJson+"');
    }
    if (objLoginJson.LoginSuccess == "1") {

    }
    else if (objLoginJson.LoginSuccess == "0") {

        $('#UserName').attr();
        $('#Password').attr();
        $('#TestTokenNumber1').attr();
        $('#TestTokenNumber2').attr();
        $('#TestTokenNumber3').attr();
        $('#TestTokenNumber4').attr();
    }
    return objLoginJson;
}

Answer (score 0):

Place your string in a label and
set these properties
 ( Enabled="false" style="display: none;"). You can access the lable content in javascript 
 and after the function is executed, call the javascript functin from code. see the links below.

[Register Startup Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx) Or this [Executing Javascript from Serveside](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/09-05-05/executing-javascript-function-from-server-side-code.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Put the string in the ViewData

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery. 
On click of login, you can make a ajax request and call CreateLoginjson() method and use the returned string and pass to another javascript function.

The C# method you are calling must be public and should be attributed with [WebMethod]

you can do this in success function of the jquery-ajax request
something like..

```
$.ajax(
 {
   //other options, url,data etc.
   success: function(response) {
     GetLoginJson(response.d); // d holds your returned string.
   }
 }
);
```

Thanks