# How to pass file location to viewer.html instead of querystring (?file=) in pdf.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net, pdf.js

Using pdf.js, I want to pass only file id number instead of file url then I will retrieve the file location(file url) from database with that file id number. I want all that process withing the viewer.aspx (I changed it to aspx file) and that viewer.aspx is embedded within a page.
Now I am able to see the pdf viewer with default pdf file after embedding it. But I can't handle with pdf viewer instead of passing file url....

Any idea ???

Please do me a favor. Thank you so much.

Comment: use the session variables if you don't want to use querystrings. Your question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: ok, thank you, one more questions, Please...
With this session value , how can I pass it to pdf.js ??

Comment: oh wait you can just put your variable in your as a js variable using `<%=yourc#variable%>` in your web form and set the variable value in the page load. here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553680/how-do-you-pass-variables-from-c-sharp-to-javascript