# Get value from HTML input element from Angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get the value from an HTML element from Angular controller.

```
   <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myControler">
<br />

<input id="Text1" type="text"  runat="server" value="aValue" /
```

My controller :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.controller("myControler", function ($scope, $document) {

    var name = angular.element($('#Text1')).val();
     console.log(name);

});
```

But name returns "undefined"...

Please, what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 17):

`angular.element` is an alias for jquery `$`.

You could access that element like this: `angular.element('#Text1').val();`

`ng-model` is the angular way to do this though. You can set the value from ASP using ng-init

```
<input id="Text1" type="text"  runat="server" ng-model="inputVal" ng-init="inputVal='aVal'">
```

And this can be accessed from the controller using the scope `console.log($scope.inputVal);`

JSfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/n1oppeu2/

Comment: value field is not needed when `ng-model` is used

Comment: I added an example for you

Comment: There is a convension that model name should have a dot inside it otherwise it'll lost in the $scope's realm

Comment: Hi , Preston. I can't use ng-init because this value will be filled from a code-behind Asp.net page...

Answer (score 7):

Why you need angular element to access form element ??

You can get and set value by binding model to it

like this

```
<input id="Text1" type="text"  runat="server" ng-model="input.field1" />
```

controller

```
$scope.input={
  field1:''
}
```

Comment: This element "Text1" will be filled from a code-behind Asp.net form.Then I'll use it's value inside the controller. If I bind it to a scope variable, the controller reset it's value.

Comment: unless you use the controller to set the ng-model to what was given by asp.net

Comment: @GCoe see my answer about initializing the model from the input tag

Comment: I just wanna to know , If you will access everything from .cs file then why you need angular for ?  If you wanna angular badly, then try to use server side code only data save and retrive and let angularjs handle other

Comment: Hi Anik, I'm trying to pass a collection of points ( company name, lat, long ) from .cs to a controller that will plot these points at a map with ngmap.

Comment: You don't need angular for that task. You can use plain javascript for do this task. take a look in this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553680/how-do-you-pass-variables-from-c-sharp-to-javascript`

Answer (score 2):

Using angular element selector #

```
<input id="Text1" type="text"  runat="server" value="aValue" />

console.log(angular.element('#Text1').val());
```

or

```
console.log(angular.element('#Text1')[0].value);
```

Comment: Accessing to the DOM from a controller is a bad practice. DOM should be accessed only inside directives.

Comment: @mpolci I've been trying to figure out how to get input in AngularJS for several days now; please elaborate with a thorough example in which I can take the user input and then compare it to data inside of the controller.