# C# winforms javascript not working

Tags: javascript, c#, html, winforms

I am using a web browser for C# that is hosting some html which I pass as a string. The html has some JavaScript that allows the users to jump to anchor elements. However I get an JavaScript error saying that The url is invalid.
Basically how I pass the html is:

```
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = "html stuff"
```

Is there anyway to pass the html as a string to the webBrowser and have the javascript working correctly.

Edit:
here's a working example of the html.

```
       <html>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--

    body {
    margin-bottom: 500px;
    padding: 0;
    }

    h3 {
    margin-top: 100px;
    }

    .Return {
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    }

    -->
    </style>
       <body>
       <h3><a name="a1">a001</a></h3>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>

    <h3><a name="a2">a002</a></h3>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>

    <h3><a name="a3">a003</a></h3>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>


    <h3><a name="a4">a003</a></h3>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>
    <p>paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text</p>



      <script type='text/javascript'>document.onkeydown = checkKey;var i=1;var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a').length;function checkKey(e) { e = e || window.event;if (e.keyCode == '37') {if(i>1){i--;location.hash = '#a'+i;}}else if (e.keyCode == '39') {if(i<=a){ i++; location.hash = '#a'+i;}}}</script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use a script. Perhaps take a look at this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553680/how-do-you-pass-variables-from-c-sharp-to-javascript ?

Comment: Show a minimal, reproducible example.  `html stuff` is not helpful.

Comment: The script in html example executes. What't the problem?

Comment: I have this html in a web browser in C#, and the html is stored in a string. When I run it, i get a javascript error saying that the url is invalid. I am trying to store the html in the program memory, without having to create a file.