# Why am I not able to pass latitude and longtitude to a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm passing a model from the database with a lat and long variable to the view which then passes it to the javascript file. But whenever I run the website I'm getting the error that Lat and Lng aren't defined. They're inexistent somehow. While I can access them from the view and the values are definitely correct I checked it it's really being passed to the view. Why am I not able to pass the variables from the view to the JS file correctly?

```
function initMap() {
            var uluru = { lat: Lat, lng: Lng };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 15,
                center: uluru
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: uluru,
                map: map
            });
        }



        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;

        namespace Google.Models
        {
            public class Marker
            {
                public int MarkerID { get; set; }
                public string Adres { get; set; }
                public float Lat { get; set; }
                public float Lng { get; set; }
            }
        }

    @model Google.Models.Marker


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/custom.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <script src="~/js/googleMap.js"></script>
        <script>
            var Lat = @Model.Lat
            var Lng = @Model.Lng
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>@Lat</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <center><h1>Responsive Google Map</h1></center>
            <div class="row">    
                <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 top-buffer">
                    <div id="map"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 top-buffer"></div><h1>Contact Informatie</h1></div>
            </div>
        <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCUxVA8CRavXv6yP5M4rIuSK9xJt8kgPwg&callback=initMap"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you pass variables from c# to javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553680/how-do-you-pass-variables-from-c-sharp-to-javascript)

Comment: No I'm having trouble with it

Comment: You having trouble with it doesn't make it not a dupe.

Comment: It's really not the same. He's got trouble with a different topic.

Comment: Use `var Lat = @Html.Raw(Json,Encode(Model.Lat))` to correctly assign the model values to your variables

Answer (score 0):

Heavily edited my answer based on new information you've provided. Is the `#map` div visible? It needs a height and width.

I don't think the Google Maps reference will work in the below Stack Overflow snippet, but this code is working in a local environment.

```js
function initMap() {
      var uluru = { lat: Lat, lng: Lng };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: uluru
      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: uluru,
        map: map
      });
      
      console.log(Lat);
      console.log(Lng);
    }
```

```html
<html>
 <script>
  var Lat = 43.5765631;
  var Lng = -116.274815;
 </script>

 <body>
    <div id="map" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCUxVA8CRavXv6yP5M4rIuSK9xJt8kgPwg&callback=initMap"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried that just now and it's giving me the same error

Comment: Are you receiving an actual error message in the JavaScript console or is it just not working?

Comment: I fixed the error. The razor syntax wasn't good when assigning the values but now I'm getting an empty map. Seems like the variable types aren't good maybe?

Comment: Yes this is definitely working. But I can't make it work with variables retrieved from the database and using '@Html.Raw(Model.Lng)' so using the model. Do you know why I get a working map with values and an empty grey not working map when using variables in the HTML script var value assignment?

Comment: I'm not sure, it could be one of many things. Does your ViewModel definitely have data when it is passed to the view?