# Trying to get javascript variable in vb.net codebehind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a function where I am trying to get the username and password that the user entered. It IS being stored in "unixName" and "unixPass" on the client side. I have dUnixName and dUnixPass which one is a hidden input and the other is a label. They are different because I was playing around with different ways at getting this to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//        Internet Explorer/Firefox needs this script to show radio selection after Modal Popup
function enableRDO() {
    document.getElementById("rdoUnix").checked = true;
   // document.getElementById("dUnixName").value = document.getElementById("unixName").value;
    //document.getElementById("dUnixPass").value = document.getElementById("unixPass").value;
    document.getElementById('<%=dUnixName.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById("unixName").value;
    document.getElementById('<%=dUnixPass.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById("unixPass").value;
    return true;
};
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what the problem is?  Are you saying that the value you're trying to put into `dUnixName` is not available on the server at post-back?

Comment: Correct. I have a modal window asking the user for their username and password. It is putting the value into dUnixName/dUnixPass. I want to be able to use dUnixName in the codebehind file. As of right now using IE it is not available for me. I have MsgBox popups testing to see if the server is able to call the variables. It is not working atm.

Comment: Please can you edit your question to show all the controls you are trying to copy the values **from**, all the controls you are trying to copy the value **to**, the current JavaScript function - and also state **where** you are checking for the return value (i.e. which event such as `Init`, `Load`, etc)?

Comment: Hmmm... not sure.  Have you tried running debug `alert("...");` calls in your javascript to prove that the objects are being found correctly?  I can thoroughly recommend [FireBug for FireFox](http://getfirebug.com) or use the developer tools under IE or Chrome (F12 on both).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly: You have a value in javascript that you want to pass back to the server on a post back?  Thats no problem, store the value in a an ASP:HiddenField and read it out in code behind.  If I misunderstood your question let me know.

See: [Access an asp:hiddenfield control in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252222/access-an-asphiddenfield-control-in-javascript)

***Example***

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test() {
            alert(document.getElementById('<%=txtBox.ClientID %>').value);

            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server" />
        <button onclick='test()'>Client Side Test</button>

    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnServer" runat="server" Text="Server Side Test" 
        onclick="btnServer_Click" style="height: 26px" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>  


protected void btnServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //read value here
    string test = txtBox.Text;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do. I followed your link but I don't know if that matches it though. I changed the javascript to             document.getElementById("<%= dUnixName.ClientID %>").value = document.getElementById("unixName").value;
            document.getElementById("<%= dUnixPass.ClientID %>").value = document.getElementById("unixPass").value;" and it still isn't passing the value. I am calling it in my codebehind as Dim UNIXUSERNAME As String = dUnixName.Value
        Dim UNIXPASSWORD As String = dUnixPass.Value

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using ASP.Net textboxes...?

Comment: I was, in my original code you will see "<asp:TextBox ID="dUnixPass" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />". I was trying to play around with HiddenView and textboxes but I can't get either to work. It is very frustrating :(

Comment: It also seems that this code has been working just fine in Google Chrome but not in Internet Explorer 9...

Comment: Your example is working great with Google Chrome but not IE. Same issue I was experiencing =/

Comment: Odd, I only tested it in IE... I wonder if you have some issue with your setup?

Comment: I just added your code in a new file and it worked fine in IE. I pasted my whole code, I'm going through and checking for any syntax errors where IE may throw a fit. So far I haven't found any.

Comment: BAH! Figured it out! It is due to me not having the end of the form tag wrapping the modal window. Thanks for your help. I am going to edit out the majority of my code for privacy reasons!