# Know which tab is selected from codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css

I have this situation:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-1"><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2"><span>Two</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3"><span>Three</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and also have a button

```
<asp:Button ID="Button" runat="server" OnClick="Button_Click" />
```

my js is

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".tabs").tabs();
        $('.reWrapper').css('width', 'auto');
        $('.reWrapper').css('min-width', 'inherit');
    });
</script>
```

In my codebehind I want to know which tab I am in and depending on the tab I will save the formulary of the tab.

How would I know from my codebehind which tab is selected? I need to check first which tab was selected to save one information or another, but really have no idea hot to get the selected tab? Thanks

> I dont know if this is a good idea, what i am doing is to convert my
>   html controls to server, and out onserverclick for each LI, and then
>   ask in the same method for all the LI onserverclick which one was
>   clicked and then assign the tabId to a hiddenfield. My question now,
>   how would I know wich link was clicked (I have the same method for all
>   the LI). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Convert Html Control to Server control and check in code  behind server control contain active class or not if get active class  its a active tab

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by active class?

Comment: How could I know if the control server has an active class?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a client side code that will store a variable in an asp.net hidden field, indicating which tab is selected. And then in the code behind, you can access it by using the HiddenField.Value property

Comment: What kind of hidden field? Could be a literal? is it possible to check if the converted html control to server control has the active class? Is there anyway? Thanks. Besides that where I call the client method to store the value?

Comment: The control is "<asp:HiddenField ", to call the client method, I think you need to check if the "ul" html object has a selected index event. To see how to set the hiddden field value at client side, and access it from server side, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252222/access-an-asphiddenfield-control-in-javascript

Comment: To get the active class, I am not sure honestly... :(

Comment: I think you can use this to get the selected <li> $('ul').find('li').eq(index).css('ActiveTab'); where ActiveTab is a css that you can give to the selected <li> element\

Comment: I was trying but says Index was undefined...is there other way I dont need to use client side? thanks!

Comment: You can use the asp.net Tab Panel Control, check http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/Tabs-Control.ashx

Comment: Yes I know but it was not designed by me (the site) I have to handle myself wich what I have now.

Answer (score 0):

Same as 
Hassan Mokdad
suggested you can write a javascript function using which you can set value of Hidden field that indicates which tab is selected.

And in code behind on button's click event you can get value of that hidden field and can do Database operation.